# Upgrade OutBound Email audience manager from Tridion 2009 sp1 to Tridion 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013, audience-manager, outbound-email, upgrade

I was able to successfully upgrade Upgrade OutBound Email audience manager from Tridion 2009 sp1 to Tridion 2013 sp1. When I access my newsletter sign up which executes PS_CONTACTS_CREATE store procedure fails. Please see the error message on the presentation server.

"Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission

Comment: By the way, please take the time to format your question so it is readable. There's a lot of information in there that is easily missed because it's all mushed together :) 

You can click on the question mark in the top-right corner of the toolbar to see information on the Markdown formatting features, such as how to make lists, how to format code, etc. Familiarizing yourself with these features will greatly improve your questions and the answers you get :)

Answer (score 1):

> "Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo"
>   does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you
>   do not have permission"

This seems to suggest that the database does not have an owner (or it's an owner that is different from what is expected). I don't know how you ended up with that, but perhaps the import of the backup caused it.

Anyway, you can see the current owner by executing the following SQL:

```
sp_helpdb 'tridion_submgmt'
```

(assuming your database is named the default -- otherwise substitute your own)

On my system, this owner is 'sa'.

If you want to set the owner, you can do this with the following SQL:

```
use tridion_submgmt 
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

(Again, substitue the database name and 'sa' as appropriate)

Of course, you should **only do this if** I'm right about the owner being *null* or some other unexpected user.

Comment: Hi Peter thanks for the response. I did try updating the owner but it did not work. I had to delete and create the user again and I have given access to the DB. I changed the owner to sa it worked. I will try to update the owner to TMSSMUSER and will see if it works. thanks again.